# Show spinner ($.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()) on just one element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Is there a simple way to show the spinner (`$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()`) on just one element/region ?

I'm loading this element's content via `AJAX`, so until it's finished I have to block it and show this spinner.

Comment: Just an FYI, if possible move to use $.mobile.loading( 'show' ) instead. $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg() is being deprecated in JQM 1.2

Comment: I should mention $.mobile.loading method is only in JQM 1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't. Take a look at the [docs](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/methods.html), you can just customize the message or hide the spinner, but not making it fit to a element.
If you just want to show a spinner on some element loading, use the `beforeSend` and `complete` options of the `ajax` method to hide/show it

Comment: Because of the first sentence. This is possible, just not by default.

Comment: @Jasper go ahead and post your answer, we all would be glad to learn something new

Comment: @Jasper, I agree with davids, I'd be glad to know how it can be accomplished. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See my answer, there is one way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the CSS position of the loading spinner to appear over a certain region. Here is a code example that both shows and hides the loading spinner over an element:

```
//this is an IIFE, it creates an enclosure around the code that separates it from global code
(function ($) {

    //a flag so we know what state the loading spinner is in
    var isShowing = false;

    //this example is binding to all link elements
    $('a').on('click', function () {

        //check if the loading spinner is already showing
        if (isShowing === false) {

            //the loader is not showing, so create an overlay in the container element
            var $con = $('#container').append('<div class="container-overlay"></div>');

            //now position the loader over the container
            $('.ui-loader').css({
                position : 'absolute',
                top      : ($con.offset().top + ($con.height() / 2)),
                left     : ($con.offset().left + ($con.width() / 2))
            });

            //fade-in the overlay and show the loading spinner
            $con.children('.container-overlay').fadeIn(500);
            $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

            //set the flag so next time around we hide the spinner
            isShowing = true;
        } else {

            //fade-out the overlay
            $('#container').children('.container-overlay').fadeOut(500, function () {

                //remove the overlay from the DOM
                $(this).remove();

                //hide the loader
                $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();

                //reset the CSS of the loader element
                $el.css({
                    position : 'fixed',
                    top      : '50%',
                    left     : '50%'
                });
            });

            //set the flag so next time around we show the loading spinner
            isShowing = false;
        }
    });​
})(jQuery);
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CkUZf/

For the demo (link) above, I used this CSS for the overlay element:

```
#container .container-overlay {
    display    : none;
    height     : 100%;
    background : #000;
    background : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}​
```

It would also be possible to append the loader element to whatever container you want to "load" but `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()` automatically resets the loader element so you'd have to disable that code in the jQuery Mobile include (which is why I went this the lighter CSS version above).

**Update**

This is probably more like what you were thinking:

```
$.fn.customMobileSpinner = function (options) {

    var defaults = {
            url             : null,
            fadeDuration    : 500,
            bgColor         : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
            bgColorFallback : '#000'
        };

    //merge the defaults and options objects
    options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    //make sure the URL is specified
    if (options.url !== null) {

        //only work with the first element passed-in
        var $element = this.eq(0);
        $element.append(
            $('<div class="container-overlay" />').css({
                display    : 'none',
                height     : '100%',
                width      : '100%',
                background : options.bgColorFallback,
                background : options.bgColor
            })
        ).children('.container-overlay').fadeIn(options.fadeDuration);

        //update loader CSS
        $('.ui-loader').css({
            position : 'absolute',
            top      : ($element.offset().top + ($element.height() / 2)),
            left     : ($element.offset().left + ($element.width() / 2))
        });

        //show spinner
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();

        //create AJAX call
        $.ajax({
            url : options.url,
            success : function (response) {
                $element.fadeOut(options.fadeDuration, function () {
                    $element.html(response).fadeIn(options.fadeDuration);
                    $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();

                    //reset loader CSS
                    $(".ui-loader").css({
                        position : 'fixed',
                        top      : '50%',
                        left     : '50%'
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Then you just call this method on a jQuery object:

```
$('#some-container').customMobileSpinner({
    url : 'some-url'
});
```

Comment: Great contribution!! We could discuss about the simplicity of this solution, as @Tal's question begins saying if "Is there a simple way to show the spinner...", but that doesn't make this answer worse.

Comment: I updated my answer to a specific example. I turned the code into a jQuery plugin and now calling it on elements is a one-liner.

Comment: Your solution is great, and easy to use, but when @Tal asked if there is a simple way to show `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()` in a container, I thought about the method options or configuration, not writing a plugin. So, well, there are loads of things you can do with a bunch of jQuery, but just ask yourself if you would follow this approach for the given purpose. There're some drawbacks, for instance, you are modifying the loader's class, what happens if you want to use `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()` as usual? I wouldn't say your solution is wrong... and neither is mine.

Comment: I suggest experimentation before deciding why something won't work. For instance, jQuery Mobile automatically resets the loading spinner every-time you call `$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg()`, something I found-out while messing with the code for this answer. The one thing I can guarantee is that if you explore options all the time you will be a more knowledgeable developer. I suppose it's really about how much time you're willing to spend on development. To answer your question, **yes**, I would use this solution, but that's because I understand in-depth how it works since I've spent the time.

Comment: I'm afraid that wouldn't be "a simple way", as in few lines of code. However I really appreciate your effort here, which is really inspiring.